Building a NAS - cannot get HDDs to work, is there something I'm doing wrong?
I am trying to build a NAS, here are the specs of the system:
- AMD Ryzen 9 7950x3D
- 128GB DDR4 (3200MHz?)
- RTX 4070
- 1TB 970 evo
- 4 6TB WD Red Plus
- Focus GX-1000 1000w PSU

So whenever I plug in any of the hard drives to the system with SATA power, it just immediately clicks off, I'm assuming it's some kind of OVP because I have to unplug the CPU pins and power cycle the system to get it to turn back. I have tried the drives with 3 different systems, different PSUs, different cables, and even bought a 6TB WD purple to see if maybe there was some weirdness going on with nasware3.0 or something. Same problem. We also had a couple 12TB drives before that also were not working. We are at 7 different drives that do not work with any of our systems. What is going on?
One of the computers had 3 drives in it already that were working, and we would unplug the sata data and power, plug it into one of the high capacity drives, and boom nothing. Plug the original drive back in and it works.
I just cannot figure out what is going on. Even tried taping pin 3, and pins 1 - 3 just in case it had something to do with PWDIS, however even if that was the issue, all the info I can find about it says the drive should still spinup with no sata data plugged in, but that is not the case.
We had a WD80EZAZ laying around that wasn't working and tried the tape on pin 3 trick on that bad boy, and that revived it. So that just confirms to me even more it's not PWDIS.
A couple of the systems are windows, and the NAS machine has Ubuntu on it so I don't think it's an OS issue either, which again doesn't make sense since the drives never even spin up during POST

how sure are you that your NAS is expecting SATA and not SAS?

Well technically my NAS is just a regular desktop computer with beefy specs... but the drive itself is a WD60EFPX which according to its documentation is SATA
https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-red-plus-hdd/product-brief-western-digital-wd-red-plus-hdd.pdf

everything you describe sounds to me like you aren't getting sufficient wattage. are you sure the power you are getting from the wall is clean? is there a UPS involved?

That’s what I was thinking too, so I tried a few different power supplies with similar outcomes. Yes there is a 1000W 1500VA UPS between the wall and the NAS when we were testing. I’m thinking maybe the power supplies are struggling with the surge to get the disks spinning up? Are there any purpose built PSUs I can look into?

is this system on at the time you connect the disks? I guess i hadn't put it together, but your system shouldn't be on when you connect the disks. if you need hot-swapping/plugging you can work on that after you know your system works with the disks permanently installed.

Oh yeah for sure, we weren't hot swapping. Was doing a full shutoff before every test to troubleshoot. However even then, our working drives were able to be tested while the system was on just by plugging in the power real quick to see if it spins up. Probably not best practicce but we're at our wits end

So we were using a FOCUS GX 1000, and every drive we got we would first plug it into that PSU because it is what's powering the NAS. Now suspecting there is a problem with the PSU and it was just frying every drive we plugged in

all I can suggest, is power the system off, install the disks, and power it back on. do not plug/unplug any disks (power or data) from the system while its powered on. hopefully they aren't fried.
